# How to format date in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office

I want to format the date 'Tuesday, April 28th, 2020' to dd-mm-yy format in excel. How can I do that? I tried doing it with cell formatting but to no avail. I think custom formatting can help but I don't know how to use that.

Comment: Likely you have text-that-looks-like-a-date.

Comment: Yes, you are correct but I want to format it

Comment: Dates are numbers, so you have to convert it to a date first.

Comment: but when I select the date, I the format automatically changes to 'Date' in the topbar instead of 'General'

Comment: try using a formula like : `=--(REPLACE(TRIM(MID(A1,FIND(",",A1)+1,LEN(A1))),FIND(",",TRIM(MID(A1,FIND(",",A1)+1,LEN(A1))))-2,2,""))` then format the output as desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would follow @Scott Craner formula, and format it just like in the below picture.

Step 1: [Enter formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNlYA.png) *click this picture link*

Step 2: [Format as "mm-dd-yy" in the cell formatting -> custom format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTlrz.png) *click this picture link*

[Here is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eEld.png) *click this picture link*